# Pulseaudio doesn't start correctly unless I run it with strace

Tags: systemd, pulseaudio, strace, headless

So here's a weird problem that I've been experiencing.

I've been using PulseAudio to create a fake loopback interface on a Virtual Machine for music streaming purposes. A few days ago the server rebooted unexpectedly, and suddenly, the PulseAudio daemon stopped being able to bind to its socket (running as root, I'm aware this is not recommended, but this is a VM whose only purpose is to do this). It's running as root, so it should theoretically have EVERY permission to do this, so I suspected something else was happening.

Now, the PA daemon starts from a `systemd` unit. It seemed to work great from the root account running the exact same command, so I decided to try to `strace` the systemd unit to see what it was doing. However, I did this and the pulseaudio daemon bound correctly! It started up and began working as expected! So as a stopgap measure, I currently run the following command in the unit to get it working:

```
 /bin/strace -e '!all' /bin/pulseaudio --start --daemonize=no
```

My question is why on earth would running strace in front of a program change it's behavior? I think It might have something to do with environment variables, but I can't seem to figure out if strace loads them.

Edit: I should note that this VM is intentionally headless, and doesn't have a display manager. I'm using Xvfb with a 1x1 display to get dbus to work. The whole thing is a hack of sorts, but it has worked until this weekend.

Comment: Is this a CentOS machine? In that case, you may have gotten a newer `systemd` as part of CentOS 7.7 which was released a week or two ago. If you have some sort of auto-patching on, you may have gotten the minor version bump without noticing. (This would also explain the reboot.)

Comment: So it appears SELinux either became enabled, or the ruleset changed between now and the last restart. I checked the audit log, set SELinux to permissive and watched as my script now magically worked.